# Wifi direct lollipop issue

Tags: android, connection, android-5.0-lollipop, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I have an application that uses WifiP2p for communication. One device create a wifiP2pGroup and the others can connect to it.

This is working, if i create a group with an android 4.x device. But if i create a group with a lollipop (5.x) device, other devices cannot see this group.

Test devices:

- LG Optimus F6 (4.4.2)
- LG G3 (5.0)
- Samsung Galaxy Note I (4.1.2)
- Samsung Galaxy S4 (5.0.2)
- Samsung Galaxy Nexus (4.3.1)

Test cases:

Create group with:

- LG Optimus F6 - visible for all devices
- LG G3 - invisible for all devices
- Samsung Galaxy Note I - visible for all devices
- Samsung Galaxy S4 - invisible for all devices
- Samsung Galaxy Nexus - visible for all devices

All device uses the same code, so i guess the problem is in the wifiP2p under lollipop.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be visible if the device would be doing Peer discoveries etc. same time ?

I didn't do full testing on the topic yet, but earlier at least the group access point was not visible on my Nexus 5 using 501 until I started doing something else there as well.

To test this, you could try my code for [WifiPairing](https://github.com/DrJukka/WifiPairing).

Comment: Unfortunately, i cannot use WifiP2p.nsd library, because that uses API16 but my minApi level is 14.